# Sqlite - Case When from nested Select result set

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, case

I have the following SQL query in a SQLite Android database:

```
Select * from Items, Deadlines
```

Which will return me something like this:

```
id - item_id - deadline
1 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
2 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
3 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
4 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
5 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
6 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
7 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
8 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
```

And I would like to add another Result Column like lowest_deadline for every item_id. So I would like to have in the complete result set something like this:

```
id - item_id - deadline - lowest_deadline
1 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
2 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
3 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
4 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
5 - 201 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00 - 2018-02-09 10:55:00
6 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
7 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
8 - 200 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00 - 2018-02-09 10:52:00
```

You need to understand, that this query is just a simplification of my kinda longer query. So what I need is something like:

```
Select a.* 
CASE WHEN ....a.item_id???....... END AS lowest_deadline
FROM (Select * from Items, Deadlines) a
```

Does anybody know the answer? Many thanks

Comment: Items, Deadlines are full outer join ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar No full outer join, just a simple join or left join depends on the complexity of sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to key between `Items` and `Deadlines`.

```
Select  
Items.id,
Items.item_id ,
min(Deadlines.deadline) lowest_deadline
 from Items, Deadlines
where Items.item_id =Deadlines.item_id
```

group by 
    Items.id,
    Items.item_id

Comment: But I would like to not implement the whole result set to the MIN part. I hoped, that there is much better solution

Comment: Hmm, I think, that is not the answer, because over partition clause isn't supporter by Sqlite version in Android devices

Comment: so, why you do not want to use min ?

Comment: Because MIN takes all deadlines defined let's say for item_id 200. But what If I wanted just a rows from table Items, that have another condition?

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't use commas in the `from` clause.  If you want an explicit `cross join`, use `cross join`.

There are multiple ways to get what you want.  The "traditional" method would be an aggregation and `join`:

```
Select i.*, d.*, dd.min_deadline
from Items i cross join
     Deadlines d join
     (select dd.item_id, min(dd.deadline) as min_deadline
      from Deadlines dd
      group by dd.item_id
     ) dd
     on dd.item_id = i.item_id;
```

I sort of suspect that you really want only one row per item, with the minimum.  If so, you can simply do:

```
select i.*,
       (select min(d.deadline) from Deadlines d where d.item_id = i.item_id) as min_deadline
from items i;
```